# Android: Reasonable upload speed on 3G

Tags: android, file-upload, performance

What upload speed should I expect to be available to my users? This is for image attachments to emails.

A test we did over the phone for one user came out to about 100 kilobits per second.

The reason I ask is I am not sure if my unloader is creating an unusual amount of latency (edit: I mean time wasted between actual upload of a chunk). It uploads in parts using separate `HttpPost` requests and it base64 encodes the parts and sends them as POST parameters instead of using a "multipart file upload" like a browser would do.

This is the only test I have done with an end user and I don't actually own an Android phone.

Comment: I get better upload speed with my phone than I do my DSL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 Kbps does not seem so bad. The actual max speed for UMTS is 384 Kbps, but I never saw more than 250 Kbps, and that's with a very good signal. HSUPA speeds, on the other hand, can be 10 fold faster, but there are just a few phones in the US supporting it, with a lot more in Europe. Given the really big variability in speed due to signal issues, my guess is that it won't be a bottleneck in your software. You should, nevertheless, consider that phones can get into 2g zones still or even loose signal in the middle of the transfer. A failure due to a loss of signal is a much worst problem for the end user than a couple more seconds waiting for the transfer (which, anyway, should be done in the background).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if for upload or download, data transfer speed over 3G can vary a big deal depending on how close or far the user equipment is from the base station transmiting nearby and depending on the conditions he is regarding that base station... buildings nearby, inside building or outside, interference, and so on and so on. Also, the modulation used will depend on this, which will greatly change the connection speeds for users in different conditions.

In any case, the speed you get for the data transfer and the latency are two different things.

I'm not sure of the implications in your specific application and the Http protocol, but you mention separate requests. So it should work.

Comment: When I mention latency, I mean wasted time between uploads of each chunk. Sorry, I was not clear.